# GWT JUnit tries to contact the wrong IP address

Tags: eclipse, gwt, junit4

I am trying to run GWT Junit tests in eclipse Juno (right-click on test case file and "run as GWT JUnit test case"). However, JUnit fails with an exception saying the connection refused on an IP address other than the one of my client machine.

(I'm manually inserting an extra space in the URLs to avoid stackoverflow blocking the post because of bad URLs).

> Starting http://192.168.1.234:46278/org.me.MyProject.JUnit/junit-standards.html?gwt.codesvr=192.168.1.234:46971 on browser FF3
>
> logging for HtmlUnit thread
>
> [ERROR] I/O error on HTTP request
>
> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.234:46278 refused

My machine's IP address is 192.168.1.3. I have no clue from where eclipse got the other IP. Where does eclipse get the erronous address and how can I change it, preferably to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: We are going to need some more information here. What options are enabled in the GWT plugin for eclipse (On the run configurations) ? Are you connected to the internet ? The ip 234 is pointing to what ? Can you ping it ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the above question was that there was a malconfigured DNS server involved. Eclipse read the hostname of the machine and resolved it to the wrong IP number.